# Animation in Streambuilder to display Firebase Content

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I want to add some animation upon addition or removal of an object (that is constructed using streambuilder by reading data from my firebase database). How the progression works is
User adds task => Task gets added to firebase =>Streambuilder detects change and rebuilds UI (jaggedly due to no animation) => User removes task => Task gets removed from firebase => Streambuilder detects change and rebuilds UI (Again jaggedly as their is no animation)

**I want to add animation at the two points where streambuilder is rebuilding the UI and adding the Todo task. Is there any way to do this?**

I have researched about the package `animated_stream_list` but really could'nt understand how I could incorporate it into my code. Any insight about that would be wonderful.

***Code:***

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Users')
              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
              .collection('UserTasks')
              .orderBy("Timestamp", descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                //Container that containes text (Make function later on) START
                return GestureDetector(
                  onDoubleTap: () {
                    //Deleting task when user taps on it
                    deletetask("${document.data()['Todo']}");
                  },
                  child: AnimatedContainer( 
                  // UI elements .....
                  child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              "${document.data()['Todo']}")
                              )
                              .....
                ),   //Animated container end                            
                );   //Gesture Detector end
                
                
              }).toList(),
            );      //Listview
          },
        ),          //StreamBuilder
```

Answer (score 1):

AnimatedSwitcher might help here. It animates between widgets automatically whenever the child changes. In your case, inside stream builder, wrap your widget with animated switcher. Check this for more information. [Animated Switcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html)

There is a good video explanation of how to use it in the page. For more info, refer to the documentation.

Comment: The problem with animated switcher is that if I add a condition to fade away the user tapped task , then all the other widgets also disappear. I cant single out one particular widget that the user taps. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

try using [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html).

use `snapshot.data.docChanges` to detect changes and
call `insertItem` or `removeItem` based on `docChange.type`

maybe something like this

```dart
snapshot.data.docChanges.forEach((docChange) {
  if (docChange.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
    AnimatedListState.insertItem();
  } else if (docChange.type == DocumentChangeType.removed) {
    AnimatedListState.removeItem();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When anything updates then StreamBuilder rebuilds the widget automatically. Internally, StreamBuilder calls `State.setState`. So, according to me, if you want to add an animation when the item is deleted, you have to add it on the Gesture detection. In your code snippet, you had added on GestureDetection that will remove the item on double click. So, you can do one thing. When the user double clicks, play the animation for some seconds and then call the function to delete the item. After that, StreamBuilde will rebuild itself and displays the updated content.

Hope this will solve your use case. If you have any problem further, please comment below.

Comment: So how do I tell the animated container to change its properties when the user double taps because you cant get specific index in streambuilder.